# If Kazakhstan's citizen visited Indonesia/Ukraine while wearing shirt with flag of Kazakhstan's armed forces, would he face any legal punishment?

Tags: is-x-legal, indonesia, ukraine

Here is the flag:
[image]

I want answers for each country (in one post if possible). Both countries banned communist symbols, but Kazakhstan isn't a communist country. So maybe it's possible to argue, that given this context this red star in the flag isn't a communist symbol, it merely looks indentical as such symbol, but it doesn't have the meaning of this symbol. Or maybe there are some other considerations that can be used against punishing display of this flag.

Comment: Why in particular Indonesia and Ukraine? They're not really close to each other...

Comment: @PMF Because they are the only countries that have de-facto general ban on communist symbols, as far as I know.

Comment: Apparently Indonesian [law does **not** explicitly declare a ban on symbols of communism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bans_on_communist_symbols)

Comment: @Rick But display of such symbols can be interpeted as promoting forbidden ideology of Communism. Then it boils down to if public display of this flag would be likely considered as promotion of Communism in Indonedia

Comment: So, as I understand it, the question is not whether it is a good idea to visit Ukraine or Indonesia, or whether it is wise to wear a particular patch, it is simply asking whether it is *legal* under the laws of Ukraine and Indonesia. Also, AFAIK the rareness of questions about Kazakh law does not make the question off topic.

Comment: @user6726 yep, pretty much.